# Microsoft Access combo box overwriting first record

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I have a combo box with 4 employees in it

```
ID       EmployeeNumber        FirstName        LastName
1        010101                Joshua           Dalley
2        020202                Jessica          Daze
3        030303                Jason            Bruyere
4        040404                Jeremy           Bob
```

when I display the combo box, everything seems normal. I have a onChange() code which updates the firstName / lastName text box

```
Private Sub cboEmployeeNo_Change()
    Me.txtFirstName.Value = Me.cboEmployeeNo.Column(2)
    Me.txtLastName.Value = Me.cboEmployeeNo.Column(3)
End Sub
```

My problem is, when I close my form frm_login, while I have selected any ID, it seems to always overwrite the first ID=1 with the last employee selected in the combo box. I do not know how to fix this. It only changes the FirstName and LastName, while EmployeeNumber stays the same.

Example

```
ID       EmployeeNumber        FirstName        LastName
1        010101                Jason            Bruyeye
2        020202                Jessica          Daze
3        030303                Jason            Bruyere
4        040404                Jeremy           Bob
```

This would be my table if I close it while viewing the ID=3

```
Default View: Single Form
Allow Form View: Yes
Allow Datasheet View: No
Allow PivotTable View: No
Allow PivotChart View: No
Scroll Bars: Neither
Record Selectors: No
Navigation Buttons: No
Border Style: Thin

Record Source: tbl_employee

Allow Filters: No
Allow Edits: Yes
Allow Deletions: No
Allow Additions: No
Data Entry: No
```

Comment: Of course it only changed the first and last name, that's all you're changing in your code. How is your form set up?

Comment: are you implying my cboEmployeeNo_change() is whats causing me all this problem?

Comment: Comment out the `OnChange()` method, and see if your problem occurs.

Comment: So when your Record Source is tbl_employee, you're *editing* the records by changing the values of `FirstName` and `LastName`. While the form may be on the first record, you select `Jason` is change the values for the *first record's* data.

Comment: It doesn't change the data anymore, but my textbox aren't displaying the name after selecting the employee number from the combobox. How should I get around this, since my code is obviously breaking it

Comment: Does your form need to be tied to `tbl_Employee`? You could also try setting `Allow Edits: No`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by tied to `tbl_Employee`, since I do need the data from the `tbl_Employee`. My combobox is currently unbound as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first confusion may be setting the `Recordsource` of the form to `tbl_employee`. You can load the combobox with the values from `tbl_employee`. I see nothing in your question that leads me to believe there should be a `Recordsource` for the form.

You can set the Control Source of your textboxes to the values of the combobox.

1. Right Click txtFirstName -> Properties -> Data -> Control Source :
   cboEmployeeNo.Column(2)
2. Right Click txtLastName -> Properties -> Data -> Control Source :
   cboEmployeeNo.Column(3)

From [Microsoft Support Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209738):

```
To display the *YourField* column of the current combo box selection, create a text box control. Make the text box a calculated control by defining the following expression as the ControlSource for the text box
=[cboControlName].Column(1)
where cboControlName is the name of the combo box. The Column property makes the text box (calculated control) read-only.
```

Comment: I always assume a form should always be base off a Query. Wont having no control source for a form, render it useless?

Comment: @JoshuaDalley Depends on what you're using it for, really.

Comment: `txtFirstName / txtLastName = #Name?` after removing the control source from the form, and entering `Me.cboEmployeeNo.Column(2) / Me.cboEmployeeNo.Column(3)` into the controlsource for the textbox.

Comment: @JoshuaDalley Were txtFirstName / txtLastName fields in `tbl_employee` ? You may want to delete those 2 fields, create 2 new textboxes with the same names, and set the recordsource for the combobox using tbl_employee.

Comment: Yes they are fields in the `tbl_employee` and are needed to keep track of employee number belongs to this person.

Comment: Are you implying to delete my txtbox to create 2 unbound txtbox which relies on the `cboEmployeeNo.columns` to populate it?

Comment: @JoshuaDalley And that was why you were changing records you did not want to change... And yes to your second comment. Create 2 unbound txtbox which rely on the combobox.

Comment: it's still giving me the `#Name?` even thought my combo box is still displaying `employeeNo` at column 1, and its still retrieving `firstname` and `lastname` for column 2/3.

Comment: @JoshuaDalley Did you spell everything correctly? Inside your textboxes, they should say `=[cbo.EmployeeNo].[Column](2)` and `3`. Make sure your combobox ACTUALLY has 3 columns.

Comment: Yes, I just triple check. `[Me].[cboEmployeeNo].[Column](3)` I even tried with column 0 and 1, and 1 = EmployeeNo which the combobox is displaying, and it was still giving me the same error.

Comment: What is your `RowSource` for your combobox?

Comment: `SELECT [tbl_employee].[employeeID], [tbl_employee].[employeeNumber], [tbl_employee].[firstName], [tbl_employee].[lastName] FROM tbl_employee ORDER BY [employeeNumber];`

Comment: @JoshuaDalley Duh, sorry about that. I copied your text from your question. Delete the `Me.` portion of the control source.

Comment: 1 final stupid question. Why would having ME effect it? since I thought ME was to refer to the current form objects?

Comment: @JoshuaDalley I'm not 100% sure. There was some kind of error referencing the control. I tried `Me!` also, and it gave the same error. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223099(office.11).aspx) is a good read-up about them. I'm still not quite sure though.